# How to prevent access to local file system

Tags: c#, security, acl

I have a situation in which my (C#) application can load external DLLs (not written by me) and execute code from those libraries. The libraries can be C# or CPP.

I need to make sure this external code won't access any files in my local file system (read and write) except from a specific folder.

How can i do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx

Comment: You cannot otherwise sandbox native C++ code that uses the winapi directly, other than running the process with a user account that restricts file system access.

Comment: You say c# or CPP..are they always managed libs?

Comment: Isnt possible to do wrap the call to unmanaged code in an impersonated call (logon user APIs) with restricted access, so that doesnt have to run the whole application with restricted privs but just restrict the external calls?

Comment: @Hans this is not so. There are tools for sandboxing generic code.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen third-party code that does this; for example, [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) lets you write JavaScript scripts that manipulate CLR objects, but it prevents any JavaScript-originated code paths from accessing the filesystem, Reflection, etc. by using permissions.

You can read Jint's documentation and poke through their source code for more details, but the essence of it seems to be this:

```
PermissionSet myPermissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
// or some other permission set, depending on your requirements

try {
    myPermissionSet.PermitOnly();
    // run untrusted code
} finally {
    CodeAccessSecurity.RevertPermitOnly();
}
```

A lot of things I've read say you need to create a sandboxed Appdomain (something I've never had much success with), but Jint's approach seems to work pretty well. You might have to watch out for the third-party code hooking static events that would fire later, though -- then they could escape the `PermitOnly` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application as a restricted user account and only grant the user access to that specific folder.

Comment: This is a good solution but now i have another problem - i must be able to connect to a pipe created by a java process from the Administrator user. I receive an access denied error.

Comment: have the administrator user process create the pipe with priviledges that allow the restricted user to access it

Answer (score 0):

Secure the files through the OS facilities (filesystem privs), create an account that can access only those files and use this account to run the application

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your framework, but you can use [Caspol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (Code Access Security Policy) up to .Net 3.5 (and I *think* C++ DLLs also) to specify security privileges including IO access.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Molebox, maybe it will fit your needs. Molebox lets you wrap modules to sandbox them.